# How to add elements before each occurence of string in list?

Tags: python

I have a list for which I'm trying to add the 3 consecutive elements `'A','B','C'` before each occurrence of 'D' and when the previous element be different than 'C'. I'm using `startwith()` since instead of letters in actual data are words.

This is my current attempt but is not changing anything.

```
mylist = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'D', 'E', 'W', 'B', 'D', 'W']

for idx,el in enumerate(mylist):
    if el.startswith('D') and not mylist[mylist.index(el)-1].startswith('C'):
        mylist.insert(idx,'A|B|C'.split('|'))
```

My expected output would be like this:

```
mylist = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', ['A','B','C'], 'D', 'E', 'W', 'B', ['A','B','C'],'D', 'W']
```

Then, I would flatten this output to finally get

```
out = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'W', 'B','A','B','C','D', 'W']
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What shall happen when the first element is 'D'? Insert before it or not?

Comment: Hi Kelly. Good question, I didn't considered that option since that wouldn't happen in actual data.

Comment: `mylist.index(el)` The `.index()` function returns the index of the _first_ such element in the list.  It just so happens that in this list, the first D is preceded by a C, so the `if` statement is always false.

Comment: Why are you using `.index()` anyway?  You're using `enumerate()`, so you already have the index in the variable `idx`.

Comment: you're right, should be only `mylist[idx-1].startswith('C')`. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying a list as you're iterating over it will usually cause the iteration to skip and/or repeat.  If you build an entirely new list as you iterate over the original, it's very straightforward:

```
>>> mylist = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'D', 'E', 'W', 'B', 'D', 'W']
>>> out = []
>>> for i in mylist:
...     if i.startswith('D') and out and not out[-1].startswith('C'):
...         out.extend(['A', 'B', 'C'])
...     out.append(i)
...
>>> out
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'W', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'W']
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of modifying the list while iterating over it (which rarely produces the intended results), you can add items to a new list while iterating over the original.

```py
prev = None
res = []
for el in mylist:
    if el == 'D' and prev != 'C':
        res += 'A', 'B', 'C'
    res.append(prev := el)
```

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P7cyJ7O4RMFWIVrdUV1HQd0JRDiDCBcQ4YrKCocrcYFwY7kKilLLgNr98vNSuYpSi0EmxXKl5RcppOYoZOYpQMy34lIAgsw0kKCtLUi3QmJeigJYr6ItyEKIChAAGaINFEN2DhdUQi@xoCA1L0UDrNHKFmicJtABmXklGkBJzf//AQ)

Answer (score 1):

Modifying lists is fraught with danger and is considered less than optimal programming practice.  This example creates a new list with the inserted values:

```
mylist = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'D', 'E', 'W', 'B', 'D', 'W']
new_list = []

for idx, el in enumerate(mylist):
    if el.startswith('D') and not (idx > 0 and mylist[idx-1].startswith('C')):
        new_list.extend(['A','B','C'])

    new_list.append(el)
```